# What should I do when I encounter internal compile error?

Tags: c++

I encountered the following compile error.

```
internal compiler error: in build_base_path, at cp/class.c:300
```

My compiler version is

```
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
```

I don't know what it is even after I googled it.

How do I know the solution of it?
What should I do next?

Comment: It's a bug in gcc. Fill a bug report.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak: This is the comments section.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: it would be funny if you havn't written exactly the same in your answer ;)

Comment: @MichałWalenciak: Well, answers do go in the answer section; that's kinda what it's for.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: imho writting 2 sentence long explanation doesn't deserve to be called an answer.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak: Regardless of its length, it is the answer to the question/solution to the problem, and thus does not belong in the comments section, which is for requesting clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An internal compiler error is *always* a compiler bug.

**Follow [GCC's bug reporting instructions](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/).**

Comment: thank you for telling me the site. I read it but it looks too difficult for me. I am not familiar with compiler matter. Anyway thank you again.

Comment: @mora: You can do it!